# Html. I've a problem with my carousel code, when I click on the chervon my screen page down?

Tags: html

Helle,  I am making a website. This is a project for my studies. Since I haven't studied java script yet, I wanted to make a carousel in html en css only. This one works well except that when I press the right/left chevrons, the page scrolls down. I couldn't find where the problem was in my code.
My teacher asked me to come and ask you the question.
I therefore cometo ask you for help in order to find the solution.

Many thanks in advance.
Have a good day.

```
<body> 
<div id="conteItemsCarrusel">
        <div class="itemCarousel"id="itemCarousel-1">
            <div class="carousel"id="acarrusel-1">
               <img src="./image/cuisinier.jpeg" alt="itemCarousel-1">
            </div>
            <div class="fleche">
                <a href="#itemCarousel-3">
                    <div class="gauche">
                        &#171;
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#itemCarousel-2">
                    <div class="droite">
                        &#187;
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemCarousel"id="itemCarousel-2">
            <div class="carousel"id="acarrusel-2">
                <img src="./image/photojpgd.jpg" alt="itemCarousel-2">
            </div>
            <div class="fleche">
                <a href="#itemCarousel-1">
                    <div class="gauche">
                        &#171;
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#itemCarousel-3">
                    <div class="droite">
                        &#187;
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemCarousel"id="itemCarousel-3">
            <div class="carousel"id="acarrusel-3">
                <img src="./image/serveur.jpeg" alt="itemCarousel-2">
            </div>
            <div class="fleche">
                <a href="#itemCarousel-2">
                    <div class="gauche">
                        &#171;
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#itemCarousel-1">
                    <div class="droite">
                        &#187;
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Why<sub>My page scrolls when I click on the chevrons and I don't know where is the problem in my code</sub>

Comment: It looks like this would need js for this to work properly - you are using links as your chevrons so without js, the links will just jump to where you have asked them to go

Answer (score 0):

The **point** of `href="#foo"` is to link to an element on the page and scroll directly do it.

You are presumably (you didn't include your CSS in your question) using `:target` to style that element. `:target` is designed so you can add additional styling to the element to draw more attention to it that it would get from just being at the top of the screen.

You appear to be trying to get the styling of the element linked to element without triggering the primary effect of linking to it.

You can't do that.

If you want a carousel, then use JavaScript. It's the right tool for the job.